# Trying to write a simple check value query in PHP....total noob in php..sorry

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to check a value that is normally 0 or 1 can use NULL if I have to, would rather not though.  Even if the value is "1" still gettin "0" on echo. Why?

```
<?php
$VIN = "76543212345678654";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'SOLD' from tblinventory WHERE 'VIN' = '$VIN'");
if ('SOLD' !== NULL) {echo ("1");}else{echo ("0");}
?>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong identifiers for your columns, being quotes; remove them. You're also not querying correctly. You need some form of loop.

Comment: unwrap your columns or wrap it with `

Comment: THe column names are VIN and SOLD, what identifiers am I supposed to use?

Comment: WHERE 'VIN' = '$VIN' needs to be WHERE VIN = '$VIN'  also is VIN caps in the table

Comment: You're not doing anything with $result, you are simply comparing the string "SOLD" to "NULL"

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should not put arbitrary data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove single quotes `(')` . Try something like this

```
$VIN = "76543212345678654";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SOLD from tblinventory WHERE VIN = '$VIN'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (isset($row['SOLD']) && $row['SOLD']) {
    echo ("1");
}else{
    echo ("0");
}
```

Comment: it would be $result["SOLD"] right?

Comment: isn't `$result` just  cursor? don't you need to fetch the results from it?

Comment: tried this but it echos back 1 no matter if its null or not

Comment: Glenn, that's because you're comparing the string "SOLD" to NULL, it's always going to echo 0 in this case. You need to get the $result variable and use this method `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` and then use`$result['SOLD']` to compare the value returned.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, if null it echos back "0" if not null it echos "1"

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT SOLD from tblinventory WHERE VIN = '$VIN'");
$result_array=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($result_array['SOLD'] != NULL)
 {
  echo ("1");
 }
else
{
echo ("0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do select a column with 'SOLD', change it with `SOLD` and WHERE 'VIN' = '$VIN' too...change it with WHERE `VIN` = '$VIN'

Comment: Inline code formatting is tripping up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather count VIN and do math if $result["SOLD"]==0 then not sold, if  $result["SOLD"] > 0 then sold.. Or just echo back the  $result["SOLD"]

```
("SELECT COUNT(VIN) SOLD WHERE WHERE VIN = '$VIN'");
```